# Disable loading images in firefox

Tags: firefox, 13.10

Firefox had traditionally a tab **Content** in **Preference** menu and there was option for disabling automatic image loading and controlling the feature. However, it seems that the option is removed from recent version of firefox.

My question is, is there any way to disable auto-loading of images in firefox? (without using additional extensions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to `about:config` in Firefox
2. Search for `permissions.default.image`
3. Change the value to `2` (default is `1`)

An explanation can be found here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/961547

Comment: Thanks, still missing the **exceptions** rules that can be set, waiting...

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: There was an exception button next to 'don't load images', which helped me to make exception. I'm waiting to see if there is anything still similar in the new system.

Answer (score 1):

try this: enter `about:config` into the address bar, search for the preference named `permissions.default.image`, edit it and change its value to 2.

- 1 allows all images to load,
- 2 blocks all images,
- 3 allows only images from the same site to load and blocks third-party-images.